# Linear regression : ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (1338,)

Tags: machine-learning, python, linear-regression, implementation

I try to use linear regression for insurance data . But had error on the when try to call a function with features parameter.
Here is my code:

```
def h(x):
    global w
    return np.sum(np.transpose(w)*x)
    raise NotImplementedError()
```

when try with a simple data it works fine,

```
w, x = [1,2,3], [2,3,4]
h(x)
```

the output is : 20

but when try to use the dataset, it errors:

```
features = dataset.drop(["charges"], axis=1).values
h(features )
```

it returns error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (1338,)
```

so the features looks like this:

```
array([[0.1173913 , 0.        , 0.35698144, 0.        , 1.        ],
       [0.1       , 1.        , 0.48331988, 1.        , 0.        ],
       [0.27391304, 1.        , 0.46674738, 3.        , 0.        ],
       ...,
       [0.1       , 0.        , 0.5496099 , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.15217391, 0.        , 0.3117837 , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.84782609, 0.        , 0.38216303, 0.        , 1.        ]])
```

The data i used is insurance.csv from kaggle.com

Comment: You'll have to update your weight vector `w` for the matrix multiplication to work.

Comment: i'm sorry im new to this field, how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to multiply a matrix and a vector point-wise. Such an operation is not defined. I think you should use `X.dot(w)`, where `X` is a feature $\bf matrix$ and `w` is the wights $\bf vector$. `np.dot` can operate with objects of different nature (like matrices and vectors). So in `h` I'd write `return X.dot(w)`. Also, I'd call it only with a matrix `X` (for consistency), even if there's an object it would be $X \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times d}$ in that case. Watch carefully after shapes of the objects which enter functions.